# iOS Youtube Live Stream API Error

Tags: ios, objective-c, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, live-streaming

I am trying to develop an app that allow user to live broadcast on Youtube. I already implemented OAuth 2.0 login with scopes -

**googleapis.com/auth/youtube
googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl**

It's now showing like this:
[image: see image 1]

After successfully login redirected to my app, I want to create live stream with API- **https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/liveStreams** and posting the data as well. Kindly check my following code snippet -

```
    GTMSessionFetcherService *fetcherService = [[GTMSessionFetcherService alloc] init];
    fetcherService.authorizer = self.authorization;
    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [dict setValue:@{@"title":@"FS New Vod", @"description":@"hahahahah its coming now"} forKey:@"snippet"];
    [dict setValue:@{@"format":@"360p", @"ingestionType":@"rtmp"} forKey:@"cdn"];
    [dict setValue:@{@"isReusable":@"false"} forKey:@"contentDetails"];
    NSError *error;
    NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dict
                                                       options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted // Pass 0 if you don't care about the readability of the generated string
                                                         error:&error];
    NSMutableURLRequest * req = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[@"https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/liveStreams?part=cdn,snippet,contentDetails&onBehalfOfContentOwner=sdfdsfds&onBehalfOfContentOwnerChannel=Ankush_FS&key=" stringByAppendingString:self.authorization.authState.lastTokenResponse.accessToken]] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];
    req.HTTPMethod = @"POST";
    GTMSessionFetcher *ft = [fetcherService fetcherWithRequest:req];
    ft.bodyData = jsonData;
    [ft beginFetchWithCompletionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if (error) {
            // OIDOAuthTokenErrorDomain indicates an issue with the authorization.
            if ([error.domain isEqual:OIDOAuthTokenErrorDomain]) {
                [self setGtmAuthorization:nil];
                [self logMessage:@"Authorization error during token refresh, clearing state. %@", error];
                // Other errors are assumed transient.
            } else {
                [self logMessage:@"Transient error during token refresh. %@", error];
            }
            return;
        }
        NSError *jsonError = nil;
        id jsonDictionaryOrArray =
        [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&jsonError];

        // JSON error.
        if (jsonError) {
            [self logMessage:@"JSON decoding error %@", jsonError];
            return;
        }

        // Success response!
        [self logMessage:@"Success: %@", jsonDictionaryOrArray];
    }];
```

But every time getting error -

```
Example-iOS[5413:160436] Transient error during token refresh. Error Domain=com.google.HTTPStatus Code=400 "(null)" UserInfo={data=<7b0a2022 6572726f 72223a20 7b0a2020 22657272 6f727322 3a205b0a 2020207b 0a202020 2022646f 6d61696e 223a2022 676c6f62 616c222c 0a202020 20227265 61736f6e 223a2022 70617273 65457272 6f72222c 0a202020 20226d65 73736167 65223a20 22546869 73204150 4920646f 6573206e 6f742073 7570706f 72742070 61727369 6e672066 6f726d2d 656e636f 64656420 696e7075 742e220a 2020207d 0a20205d 2c0a2020 22636f64 65223a20 3430302c 0a202022 6d657373 61676522 3a202254 68697320 41504920 646f6573 206e6f74 20737570 706f7274 20706172 73696e67 20666f72 6d2d656e 636f6465 6420696e 7075742e 220a207d 0a7d0a>}
```

What wrong I am doing here? Any other way to access youtube api services?

Kindly help!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of research I got the solution. We need to call the Youtube Data API and should provide API key and access token in the URL string. I am posting the code snippet also.
At the time of google login need to add scope and data api should enable for the particular app in google developer console.

```
@IBAction func btnYoutubeLiveDidTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    loaderWillShow(status: true)
    var scopes = GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().scopes
    scopes?.append("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube")
    scopes?.append("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl")
    scopes?.append("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload")
    scopes?.append("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner")
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().scopes = scopes
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn()
}


func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {
    loaderWillShow(status: false)
    if (error == nil) {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Broadcast Details", message: "Kindly provide us the following details.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        alert.addTextField(configurationHandler: { (tf: UITextField) in
            tf.placeholder = "Title (required)"
        })
        alert.addTextField(configurationHandler: { (tf: UITextField) in
            tf.placeholder = "Description"
        })
        let actionCancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel, handler: nil)
        let actionOkay = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction) in
            if !(alert.textFields?.first?.text?.isEmpty)! {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.loaderWillShow(status: true)
                }
                var dictData = [String: Any]()
                dictData["snippet"] = ["title": alert.textFields?.first?.text!, "description": alert.textFields?[1].text == "" ? DEFAULT_VIDEO_DESC : alert.textFields?[1].text!]
                dictData["cdn"] = ["format": "480p", "ingestionType": "rtmp"]
                dictData["contentDetails"] = ["isReusable": "false"]
                let apiMngr = APIManager()
                apiMngr.requestType = .Post
                var url = URL(string: "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/liveStreams?part=cdn,snippet,contentDetails&key=\(GOOGLE_API_KEY)&access_token=\(signIn.currentUser.authentication.accessToken!)")!
                apiMngr.startDataRequestWith(url: url, data: dictData, completion: { (response: Data?, error: Error?) in
                    if error == nil, let dicStream = apiMngr.getResponseDictionary() {
                        print(dicStream)
                        let formatter = DateFormatter()
                        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.0Z"
                        dictData = [String: Any]()
                        dictData["snippet"] = ["title": (dicStream["snippet"] as! Dictionary<String, Any>)["title"] as! String, "description": (dicStream["snippet"] as! Dictionary<String, Any>)["description"] as! String, "scheduledStartTime": formatter.string(from: Date())]
                        dictData["status"] = ["privacyStatus": "public"]
                        url = URL(string: "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/liveBroadcasts?part=snippet,status&key=\(GOOGLE_API_KEY)&access_token=\(signIn.currentUser.authentication.accessToken!)")!
                        let apiMngr2 = APIManager()
                        apiMngr2.requestType = .Post
                        apiMngr2.startDataRequestWith(url: url, data: dictData, completion: { (response: Data?, error: Error?) in
                            if error == nil, let dicBroadcast = apiMngr2.getResponseDictionary() {
                                print(dicBroadcast)
                                url = URL(string: "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/liveBroadcasts/bind?part=id,snippet,contentDetails,status&id=\(dicBroadcast["id"] as! String)&streamId=\(dicStream["id"] as! String)&key=\(GOOGLE_API_KEY)&access_token=\(signIn.currentUser.authentication.accessToken!)")!
                                let apiMngr3 = APIManager()
                                apiMngr3.requestType = .Post
                                apiMngr3.startDataRequestWith(url: url, data: [:], completion: { (response: Data?, error: Error?) in
                                    if error == nil, let dicBroadcastBind = apiMngr3.getResponseDictionary() {
                                        print(dicBroadcastBind)
                                        self.imgLiveFrom.image = UIImage(named: "YouTube.png")
                                        self.streamURL = URL(string: "\((((dicStream["cdn"] as! Dictionary<String, Any>)["ingestionInfo"] as! Dictionary<String, String>)["ingestionAddress"])!)/\((((dicStream["cdn"] as! Dictionary<String, Any>)["ingestionInfo"] as! Dictionary<String, String>)["streamName"])!)")
                                        self.sendStreamURLToServer()
                                    } else {
                                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                            self.loaderWillShow(status: false)
                                            self.showAlert(msg: ALERT_MESSAGE_PUBLISH_ERROR)
                                        }
                                    }
                                })
                            } else {
                                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                    self.loaderWillShow(status: false)
                                    self.showAlert(msg: ALERT_MESSAGE_PUBLISH_ERROR)
                                }
                            }
                        })
                    } else {
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.loaderWillShow(status: false)
                            self.showAlert(msg: ALERT_MESSAGE_PUBLISH_ERROR)
                        }
                    }
                })
            } else {
                let alert2 = UIAlertController(title: ALERT_TITLE, message: ALERT_MESSAGE_YOUTUBE_TITLE, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
                let actionCancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel, handler: nil)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.present(alert2, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
                alert2.addAction(actionCancel)
            }
        })
        alert.addAction(actionCancel)
        alert.addAction(actionOkay)
        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    } else {
        self.showAlert(msg: ALERT_MESSAGE_PUBLISH_ERROR)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this code snippet I'm able to create the live event on youtube...but my all events are being just created not getting live. "Waiting for username" this shows on video. Can you please help if you have done this?

Comment: @Ankush can you share code for self.sendStreamURLToServer()??

Comment: Hi Ankush, I'm also trying the same functionality. Could you please help me in understanding what we have to write inside the sendStreamURLToServer method?

Comment: Hi @TheTiger and iOS Lifee were you able to solve this problem??

Comment: @PrashantGaikwad Actually later client asked for not to work on this feature so we stopped working on that. So sorry.

Comment: It's okay brother. Thanks for the quick reply.